# Azure PutBlock giving me 400

Tags: c#, .net, azure, upload, azure-blob-storage

So I'm trying to upload a large file to azure by slicing it up in smaller pieces and and use PubBlock.

But every time i call PubBlock i get a 400 response and **The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.**

This is my code

```
    var blockNumber = 1;

    string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                        string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:D4}", blockNumber)));

    //upload
    blob.PutBlock(blockId, stream, null, null, new BlobRequestOptions()
    {
        RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 3)
    }, null);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's the version of storage client library are you using. Also, please share the complete code.

Comment: I'm using version 5.0.2. 

To get the full code, just add this line above.

var blob = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("test").GetDirectoryReference("test").GetBlockBlobReference("test.txt");

"BlobClient" is a instance of CloudBlobClient

Comment: Do you use the block IDs with the same length for all the blocks in the blob?